# Grothendieck Group of a Nonsingular Curve (Hartshorne Exercise II.6.11).

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, divisors-algebraic-geometry

I have copied the exercise below for reference. I was able to figure out how to do (a) and (d). Essentially the isomorphism in (d) is given by rank and determinant respectively. So let me focus on (b) and (c) in this post.

Please do not provide me with full solutions, but hints (and if solutions are easier, please hide the details for some of them).

For (b), the existence of the two step locally free resolution is doable. The statement that $\operatorname{det}(\psi(D))=\mathscr{L}(D)$ is also easy. What is stumping me is how to prove the independence of the choice of resolution. Checking that this defines a homomorphism follows from Hartshorne Exericse II.5.16(d) and by taking a simultaneous resolution.

There are two points in this long exercise that I am stuck.

*Where I am stuck:* How can I show that the definition is independent of choice of resolution?

An idea is to consider the two resolutions and use a result from homological algebra to extend the map $\mathscr{F}\rightarrow\mathscr{F}$ to a chain map $\mathscr{E_i}\rightarrow \mathscr{E_i'}$ between the two resolutions. This doesn't seem to do anything for me.

I also did some computations in the easy case where $X$ is affine and $\mathscr{F}$ is free, but then were unenlightening.

*Where I am stuck #2:*
How should I approach (c)?

I know there are answers circulating around, but I would like only a hint. Since we want a torsion sheaf at the end, I should try to to find $\mathscr{L}(D)^{\oplus r}$ such that the stalk at the generic point $\xi$ gives an isomorphism $\mathscr{L}(D)^{\oplus r}_\xi\rightarrow \mathscr{F}_\xi$. Since $\mathscr{F}_\xi$ has rank $r$, I really only need $\mathscr{L}(D)_\xi\cong \mathcal{O}_\xi$. So maybe part (b) with $\operatorname{det}(\psi(D))=\mathscr{L}(D)$ could be helpful here? Unfortunately, I do not know...

> Exercise II.6.11 The Grothendieck Group of a Nonsingular Curve Let $X$ be a nonsingular curve over an algebraically closed field $k$. We will show that $K(X) \cong \operatorname{Pic} X \oplus \mathbb{Z}$, in several steps.
>
> (a) For any divisor $D=\sum n_{i} P_{i}$ on $X$, let $\psi(D)=\sum n_{i} \gamma\left(k\left(P_{i}\right)\right) \in K(X)$, where $k\left(P_{i}\right)$ is the skyscraper sheaf $k$ at $P_{i}$ and 0 elsewhere. If $D$ is an effective divisor, let $\mathcal{O}_{D}$ be the structure sheaf of the associated subscheme of codimension 1 , and show that $\psi(D)=\gamma\left(\mathcal{O}_{D}\right)$. Then use (6.18) to show that for any $D, \psi(D)$ depends only on the linear equivalence class of $D$, so $\psi$ defines a homomorphism $\psi: \operatorname{Cl} X \rightarrow K(X)$.
>
> (b) For any coherent sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ on $X$, show that there exist locally free sheaves $\mathscr{E}_{0}$ and $\mathscr{E}_{1}$ and an exact sequence $0 \rightarrow \mathscr{E}_{1} \rightarrow \mathscr{E}_{0} \rightarrow \mathscr{F} \rightarrow 0$. Let $r_{0}=$ rank $\mathscr{E}_{0}$, $r_{1}=\operatorname{rank} \mathscr{E}_{1}$, and define $\operatorname{det} \mathscr{F}=\left(\bigwedge^{r_{0}} \mathscr{E}_{0}\right) \otimes\left(\bigwedge^{r_{1}} \mathscr{E}_{1}\right)^{-1} \in \operatorname{Pic} X .$ Here $\bigwedge$ denotes the exterior power (Ex. 5.16). Show that det $\mathscr{F}$ is independent of the resolution chosen, and that it gives a homomorphism $\operatorname{det}: K(X) \rightarrow$ Pic $X$. Finally show that if $D$ is a divisor, then $\operatorname{det}(\psi(D))=\mathscr{L}(D)$.
>
> (c) If $\mathscr{F}$ is any coherent sheaf of rank $r$, show that there is a divisor $D$ on $X$ and an exact sequence $0 \rightarrow \mathscr{L}(D)^{\oplus r} \rightarrow \mathscr{F} \rightarrow \mathscr{T} \rightarrow 0$, where $\mathscr{T}$ is a torsion sheaf. Conclude that if $\mathscr{F}$ is a sheaf of rank $r$, then $\gamma(\mathscr{F})-r \gamma\left(\mathcal{O}_{X}\right) \in \operatorname{Im} \psi$.
>
> (d) Using the maps $\psi$, $\det$, $\operatorname{rank}$, and $1 \mapsto \gamma\left(\mathcal{O}_{X}\right)$ from $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow K(X)$, show that $K(X) \cong$ $\operatorname{Pic} X \oplus \mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You need to somehow connect your two resolutions $0\to \mathcal{E}_1\to \mathcal{E}_0\to \mathcal{F}\to 0$ and $0\to \mathcal{E}_1'\to \mathcal{E}_0'\to \mathcal{F}\to 0$. What if you considered $\mathcal{E}_0\oplus\mathcal{E}_0'\to \mathcal{F}$? Can you make any nice-looking homological algebra diagrams from this? You will need some homological algebra lemmas here, and they might not be the most commonly used ones.
2. You're on the right track by starting with an isomorphism $\mathcal{F}_\xi\cong \mathcal{O}_{X,\xi}^n$. You need to improve this twice: first, promote this to an isomorphism $\mathcal{O}_X^n|_U\to\mathcal{F}|_U$ for some open $U$; second, obtain an injection on the whole curve which after some fiddling will give you the first map in your exact sequence. Once you have the map in your exact sequence, write $\mathcal{T}$ in another way and play around with arithmetic in the Grothendieck group (you may find (a) helpful here).

Comment: Okay, I mulled over the hints a bit. For 1., it is not clear to me what sort of diagram we should consider. The only map $\mathcal{E}_0\oplus\mathcal{E}_0'\rightarrow\mathcal{F}$ that makes is the addition map. Then I can fit that into a SES. That didn't give me any info.
Another method was to try and something similar to the horseshoe lemma: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horseshoe_lemma. Even if that worked, the exterior power computations didn't seem to lead anywhere...

Comment: You will need to use the 9 lemma, positioning $\mathcal{E}_0\oplus\mathcal{E}_0'$ in the center. You'll also need to make two separate diagrams in order to get all the relevant information (some portions of the diagrams will be the same).

Comment: I think I have successfully proven the first part. For the second part, I have an argument to upgrade to an injective morphism $\mathcal{O}_X^n\rightarrow\mathcal{F}$ and so we can fit this into an exact sequence s.t. we get a torsion sheaf on the right.

I don't precisely follow precisely how (a) is helpful. I suspect that the goal is to take an effective divisor $D$ and use the SES $0\rightarrow \mathscr{L}(-D)\rightarrow \mathcal{O}_X\rightarrow\mathcal{O}_D\rightarrow 0$, but I am stuck on where to go from here...

Comment: Apply $\gamma$ to the exact sequence mentioned in the statement of part (c), the exact sequence you've mentioned in your past comment (you may need to pay attention a little here with regards to the structure of $D$), and do arithmetic in the Grothendieck group. You should be able to collect terms to get what you want without doing anything too wild. (If that's not enough, let me know.)

Comment: I think I could use a more detailed hint with finding $D$. The computations don't seem to give me anything I can use..

Comment: You can choose $D$ to be effective. Represent the set of points which is the complement of $U$ as a Cartier divisor $\{(U_i,f_i)\}$ and apply lemma II.5.3 on each $U_i$. This gives you that $\mathcal{L}(-D)$ fits in to an exact sequence $0\to\mathcal{L}(-D)\to\mathcal{O}_X\to\mathcal{O}_D\to0$. Use the resulting equality in the Grothendieck group to write $[\mathcal{F}]-r[\mathcal{O}_X]=???$ and conclude from there.

Comment: @AHappyMathematician May I ask how to update an injective morphism $\mathcal{O}_X^n\to \mathcal{F}$? I have asked a question in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4662526/hartshorne-exercise-ii-6-11-c). Thank you!

Comment: @Eric You might find this helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3928656/992440
It is important that you can upgrade this to a local isomorphism, not just an injective morphism (from what I recall) and this is just due to an exercise in Hartshorne somewhere in II.5 / construction.

Comment: @AHappyMathematician I can conclude that $\mathcal{O}_X^n|_U\to\mathcal{F}|_U$ for some open subset $U$ from $\mathcal{F}_\xi\cong \mathcal{O}_{X,\xi}^n$.  But how to extend this map to $\mathcal{O}_X^n\to\mathcal{F}$?

Comment: @Eric see my answer at your [other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4662526/hartshorne-exercise-ii-6-11-c).