# Locally free resolution of coherent sheaves on nonsingular curves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, coherent-sheaves

This question is from Exercise II 6.11 of Hartshorne.

> Let $X$ be a nonsingular curve over an algebraically closed field $k$.  For any coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ on $X$, show that there exist locally free sheaves $\mathcal{E}_1$ and $\mathcal{E}_0$ of finite ranks and an exact sequence $0\to \mathcal{E}_1 \to \mathcal{E}_0 \to \mathcal{F}\to 0$.

I can prove that if $\mathcal{E}_0$ exists, then we can take $\mathcal{E}_1$ be the kernel of $\mathcal{E}_0\to \mathcal{F}$.  So it suffices to prove that $\mathcal{F}$ can be written as a quotient of a locally free sheaf of finite rank.

**The following is my attempt:**

Firstly, we can take an open subscheme $U=\operatorname{Spec}(A)$ such that $\mathcal{F}|_U\simeq \widetilde{M}$, where $M$ is a finitely generated $A$-module with generators $m_1,\cdots,m_n$. I want to extend $m_i$ to the global section of $\mathcal{F}$.  Since $X$ is a curve, $X-U$ consists of finite points.  For $p\in X-U$, we can take $U'=\operatorname{Spec}(B)$ containing $p$ and $f\in B$ such that $p=V(f)$.  Furthermore, we can assume that $m\in \mathcal{F}(D(f))\simeq \mathcal{F}(U')_f$, then $f^N m\in \mathcal{F}(U')$ for some $N$.  In this way I can extend $m$ to $U'$ by multiplying $f^N$, but what is $f^N m$ in $\mathcal{F}(U)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By proposition II.6.7, a complete nonsingular curve over an algebraically closed field is projective. By corollary II.5.18, any coherent sheaf on a scheme projective over a noetherian ring can be written as a quotient of a finite direct sum of twists of the structure sheaf. So you don't have to do this yourself and you can just cite previous results.

Comment: Thank you! Although $X$ is not necessarily a complete nonsingular curve in the question, it is a quasi-projective.  So we can extend the coherent sheaf and use corollary 5.18 to prove this result.

Comment: I would argue that the intention here is that $X$ should be a complete nonsingular curve and Hartshorne just typo'd/omitted the word "complete". Anyways, if $X$ is not complete, it is affine, and everything should be pretty quick :)

Comment: Another question: In Exercise II 6.11 (c), we need to show that, for any coherent sheaf $\mathcal{F}$ of rank $r$, there is a divisor $D$ on $X$ and an injective morphism $\mathcal{L}(D)^{\oplus r}\to \mathcal{F}$.  I can prove that $\mathcal{F}$ is isomorphic to a free module of rank $r$ in an open subset $U$, but I don't know how to extend it and relate it with $\mathcal{L}(D)$.  I have tried to extend the morphism as I have written in the post, but I am stuck.

Comment: @Eric does any of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4418096/grothendieck-group-of-a-nonsingular-curve-hartshorne-exercise-ii-6-11/4418107#4418107) help (including the comments)?

Comment: I have seen this before, but I still don't know how to extend the morphism $\mathcal{O}_U^r\to \mathcal{F}|_U$ to a morphism on $X$...

Comment: Hint: look at lemma II.5.3 and use some ingenuity to reduce the problem to that. If you'd like more help, please ask a new question - it's better to have stuff like that more easily searchable for future visitors than hidden in these comments.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I asked a new question in this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4662526/hartshorne-exercise-ii-6-11-c)